# Xcode Bots Set Current Integration Number

Tags: osx-server, xcode-bots

I had to restore my OSX Server from backup and now the latest integration number is lower than I need it to be. I am using the integration number to set the build number for beta distribution.

Is there a way to set the current integration number i.e. XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER?

Comment: Just add a number to XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER when you're using it? So you'd have `version=XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER+100`? Not great but would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode server has a REST API that allows changing the integration counter value.

Basically, you can use cURL to update the integration counter with the following command:

`curl -u <xcode-server-user>:<password> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -d '{"set_props":{"integration_counter":<desired-integration-counter>}}'
--insecure https://<xcode-server-address>:20343/api/bots/<bot-id>`

The bot-id can be obtained easily from any of the past integration logs.

For more information, check out the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/Bots.html

And also, the answer to this question:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19868